# fault in calculator functionality in android

Tags: android

I am new to android and I tried to implement a code of my own.
There is no error but the application is not working..
Here's my code...

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements OnClickListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button b0 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button0);
        b0.setOnClickListener(this);
        Button b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        b1.setOnClickListener(this);
        Button b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        b2.setOnClickListener(this);
        Button b3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
        b3.setOnClickListener(this);
        Button b4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
        b4.setOnClickListener(this);
        Button b5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button5);
        b5.setOnClickListener(this);
        Button b6 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button6);
        b6.setOnClickListener(this);
        Button b7 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button7);
        b7.setOnClickListener(this);
        Button b8 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button8);
        b8.setOnClickListener(this);
        Button b9 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button9);
        b9.setOnClickListener(this);
        Button bplus = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button12);
        bplus.setOnClickListener(this);
        Button bminus = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button13);
        bminus.setOnClickListener(this);
        Button bmul = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button14);
        bmul.setOnClickListener(this);
        Button bdiv = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button15);
        bdiv.setOnClickListener(this);
        Button bequ = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button11);
        bequ.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        EditText ed = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        if (v.getId() == R.id.button0) {

            ed.append("0");
            calc(0, v, ed);
        }
        if (v.getId() == R.id.button1) {

            ed.append("1");
        }
        if (v.getId() == R.id.button2) {

            ed.append("2");
        }
        if (v.getId() == R.id.button3) {

            ed.append("3");
        }
        if (v.getId() == R.id.button4) {

            ed.append("4");
        }
        if (v.getId() == R.id.button5) {

            ed.append("5");
        }
        if (v.getId() == R.id.button6) {

            ed.append("6");
        }
        if (v.getId() == R.id.button7) {

            ed.append("7");
        }
        if (v.getId() == R.id.button8) {

            ed.append("8");
        }
        if (v.getId() == R.id.button9) {

            ed.append("9");
        }

    }

    public void harsha(View v1) {
        if (v1.getId() == R.id.imageButton1) {
            Toast obj = Toast.makeText(this, "Hey Don't touch me",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            obj.show();
        }

    }

    private void calc(int x, View Y, EditText ed1) {
        if (Y.getId() == R.id.button12) {
            ed1.setText("");
            int d = Integer.parseInt(ed1.getText().toString());
            ed1.setText("");
            int h = x + d;
            ed1.setText(h);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the question??? Which part is not working?

Comment: add function: calc(0, v, ed);

Comment: private void calc(int x, View Y, EditText ed1) {
        if (Y.getId() == R.id.button12) {
            ed1.setText("");
            int d = Integer.parseInt(ed1.getText().toString());
            ed1.setText("");
            int h = x + d;
            ed1.setText(h);
        }

Answer (score 1):

Well, it does not work because you do not execute anything.

In onClick(View v):

```
if (v.getId() == R.id.button0) {
    ed.append("0");
    calc(0, v, ed);
}
```

This will only happen if the Id of the view is the id of 'button0'

Now when you look in the calc(int x, View Y, EditText ed1):

```
if (Y.getId() == R.id.button12) {
    ed1.setText("");
    int d = Integer.parseInt(ed1.getText().toString());
    ed1.setText("");
    int h = x + d;
    ed1.setText(h);
}
```

This will only happen if the Id of the view is the id of 'button12'

I'm not sure what you want it to do exactly, but if you want the code to be executed just change:

```
if (Y.getId() == R.id.button12)
```

to

```
if (Y.getId() == R.id.button0)
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not know your calculation problem clearly but you can try this, If your problem is not showing the result:

```
 private void calc(int x, View Y, EditText ed1) {
    if (Y.getId() == R.id.button12) {
        ed1.setText("");
        int d = Integer.parseInt(ed1.getText().toString());
        ed1.setText("");// It is useless duplicate of line
        int h = x + d;
        ed1.setText(""+h); //It is easiest way to parse int to a string
    }
}
```